# Load the csv file to MySQL with coma delimited and comma within field

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I am able to upload a csv file to MySQL however not able differentiate comma delimited words when used internal to one term.

There are 5 fields separated by "," however in some rows, one field has internal "," which separates the two words falsely that supposed to be intact term "abc, def". Below is the example.

Good rows:      field1,field2,field3,field4,field5

Rows with non-distinguish field3:     field1,field2,"field3a, field3b",field4,field5

Code:

```
$upload = mysqli_query($cons, 
    'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "file_name.csv" 
         INTO TABLE table_name 
         FIELDS TERMINATED by \'\,\' 
         LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' 
) or die(mysqli_error($cons));
```

Please note that it works fine for "Good rows" but for other type of rows, "field3b" is inserted as "field4" in MySQL table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

```
$upload = mysqli_query($cons, 
    "LOAD DATA 
        LOCAL INFILE 'file_name.csv'
        INTO TABLE table_name 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"           
);
```

NB : I switched the php single quotes to double quotes, so less escaping is needed in the query.

Comment: I wonder why PHP developers don't use [nowdoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) more often to get away from the confusion of escaping quotes.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS OPTIONALY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1"

Comment: I edited the syntax after testing it. `OPTIONALLY` is spelled with two L's, and the two `FIELDS` options should be together. Refer to syntax doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Many thanks @BillKarwin for fixing and explaining my mistakes !

Comment: My pleasure! I can't say I haven't made typos writing SO answers. :)